# Trying to make an automatic histogram (in pgfplots?)

Tags: macros, pgfplots, automation, graphs, expl3

How can I convert the automatic table generated by the macro, to an automatic histogram?
Is the best way do it using `pgfplots`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{siunitx}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage{xparse}

% **********************************************************
\ExplSyntaxOn
% **********************************************************

\tl_const:Nx \c_aw_the_alphabet_tl {abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,.;?()!' \token_to_str:N :}

\tl_new:N \l_aw_tab_rows_tl
\seq_new:N \g_aw_theor_rats_seq
\seq_new:N \g_aw_the_alphabet_seq

\seq_gset_split:Nnn \g_aw_theor_rats_seq {,}
{0.0651738,0.0124248,0.0217339,0.0349835,0.1041442,0.0197881,0.0158610,0.0492888,0.0558094,0.0009033,0.0050529,0.0331490,0.0202124,0.0564513,0.0596302,0.0137645,0.0008606,0.0497563,0.0515760,0.0729357,0.0225134,0.0082903,0.0171272,0.0013692,0.0145984,0.0007836,0.1918182}


\NewDocumentCommand {\showtable}{}
    {
      \clearpage
      \thispagestyle{empty}
      \aw_make_table:
    }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {NnV}
\cs_new:Npn \aw_make_table:
    {
      \seq_set_split:NnV \g_aw_the_alphabet_seq {} \c_aw_the_alphabet_tl
      %takes corresponding letter/theoretical ratio pairs from sequences and applies function
      \seq_mapthread_function:NNN \g_aw_the_alphabet_seq \g_aw_theor_rats_seq \aw_generate_row:nn
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \footnotesize
      \begin{tabular}{cS}
        \toprule
        {Letter}&{Actual}\\
        \midrule
        \textvisiblespace&1\%\\
        \tl_use:N \l_aw_tab_rows_tl
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}\par
    \end{table}
    }

\cs_new:Npn \aw_generate_row:nn #1#2
    {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l_aw_tab_rows_tl {#1&}
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l_aw_tab_rows_tl {\fp_eval:n{100*{#2}}\%}
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l_aw_tab_rows_tl {\\}
    }

% **********************************************************
\ExplSyntaxOff
% **********************************************************

\begin{document}

\showtable{}

\end{document}
```

---

I have try this way but I get some errors:

```
...

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{%
            /pgf/number format/use comma,%
            compat=newest}

... 

\begin{figure}
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates{%
                        (\textvisiblespace,1)
                        \tl_use:N \l_aw_tab_rows_tl%
                        };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{histogram.}
\end{figure}

...

\cs_new:Npn \aw_generate_row:n #1
    {
       \tl_put_right:Nn \l_aw_tab_rows_tl {(#1,}
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l_aw_tab_rows_tl {\fp_eval:n{100*{#2}})}
    }

...
```

Comment: There aren't answer for this question, because Is it impossible to do?

Comment: I think it's because in order to understand the question, people first have to compile a huge chunk of code without understanding what that code is supposed to do. It's not a minimal example, far from it, which really makes this too localised.

Comment: @Jake But this is the minimum code that is required for the functioning of the macro. And I have thinked that the meaning of the macro is explained from the characters table.

Comment: But the actual functionality of the macro has nothing to do with the problem. You could have written a much simpler macro that just generates some random numbers (or something like that), which would make it much easier to determine where the problem lies, and it would make it easier for others who are facing similar problems to see whether this question is relevant.

Comment: @Jake You are right, but I haven't write myself this macro, and I don't know how create other similar macro with that language of programming. So I'll try to learn how can I write something like your advice, and update this question.

Comment: @Jake I have fixed the question ;)

Comment: My feeling here is that the example still doesn't really help make the question clear. I've therefore closed: make the case and I'll of course re-open.